# R: SMOTE train() changes names of columns

Tags: r

I am trying to predict binary values using SMOTE in R since my dependent variable has only 9% positive values and 91% negative values. I am following [this](http://amunategui.github.io/smote/) as a guideline on a dummy data set which has 37 predictors that are all integers with the dependent variable as a factor. The problem is when I use the *train()*, the output model changes names of some of my columns by adding a '1' or '2' as a suffix. e.g. 'x1' or 'x2'. Thus, while using the *predict()*, this is the error I get:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x1' not found
```

I am not sure what is happening. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: I have used SMOTE via caret package and never run into such problems. Are all of your column names unique and made of "letters", "." and "_" only? If the colnames are ok, try doing smote via caret: https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html

Comment: Yes, I am using the caret package. Some column names do have letters and numbers e.g. xy2z, but that is it. It's strange that it is modifying names of other columns.  I'll refer to the link you've provided. Thank you!

Comment: The link will not help you much in that case. I would change all the colnames to be unique and letters-only and test. If the behavior persists I would remove and install caret and smote again.

Comment: In reading at the link provided I noticed "The underlying functions that do the sampling (e.g. SMOTE, downSample, etc) operate in very different ways and this can affect your results. For example, SMOTE and ROSE will convert your predictor input argument into a data frame (even if you start with a matrix)."  Perhaps this could be the problem?

Comment: The predictors that had column names changed were saved as factors. SMOTE treated them differently. I converted all columns but the dependent variable to numeric and it worked. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if there are predictors that are factors, SMOTE tends to treat them differently. I changed all predictors to numbers (*as.numeric()*) and it worked perfectly. It was silly but something worth figuring out.